# Determine the smallest $k$ for which a graph is k-partite.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, computer-science

A graph $G=(V,E)$ is said to be $k$-partite if you can partition all of the vertices of $G$ into independent sets. However, is there a way to determine the minimum value of $k$? Suppose that $G$ is 4-partite - that also means that $G$ is $(5,6,7,..., |V|)$ partite. But how do I know that $G$ is not $3$ partite or bipartite?

I know that doing it manually is an option, but only for graphs with a relatively small number of vertices and edges. But what about a graph with $100$ vertices and $200$ edges? How can I work it out then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The least number of parts you can separate a graph into is equal to its chromatic number, which is well-known to be NP-complete. The vertices of each colour correspond to the independent sets.